# Aligning my create an account form

Tags: html

I tried a lot of different things from the internet and none have worked so far. All I want is the input boxes on my form to be aligned as they are off center right now. Thanks

```
<form style="text-align:center;">
    <p><label> First Name:
        <input name="fName" id="fName"type="text" required/>
    </label>*
    </p>

    <p><label> Last Name:
        <input name="lName"id="lName"type="text"/>
    </label> *
    </p>

    <p><label> Email:
        <input name="email"id="email"type="email"/>
    </label>*
    </p>


    <p><label> Username:
        <input name="username"id="username"type="text"/>
    </label>*
    </p>


    <p><label> Password:
        <input name="password1"id="password1"type="password"/>
    </label>*
    </p>


    <p><label> Re-enter Password:
        <input name="password2"id="password2"type="password"/>
    </label>*
    </p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just align the text to right and then float your form left:

```
style="text-align:right;float:left"
```

Demo:

```html
<form style="text-align:right;float:left">
    <p><label> First Name:
        <input name="fName" id="fName"type="text" required/>
    </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>

    <p><label> Last Name:
        <input name="lName"id="lName"type="text"/>
    </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>

    <p><label> Email:
        <input name="email"id="email"type="email"/>
    </label>*
    </p>


    <p><label> Username:
        <input name="username"id="username"type="text"/>
    </label>*
    </p>


    <p><label> Password:
        <input name="password1"id="password1"type="password"/>
    </label>*
    </p>


    <p><label> Re-enter Password:
        <input name="password2"id="password2"type="password"/>
    </label>*
    </p>
    </form>
```

(also removing stars in some places replacing them with `&nbsp;&nbsp;` to show what to do in case the field shouldn't be required)

Comment: Ok. this works but I have * there because it is a "required field" however when I do not want the * there, it makes that field off centered with the rest. any way around that?

Comment: @Jor Yes, add &nbsp;&nbsp; instead of * then - check the edit.

Comment: That is giving me an error, like the page is now blank when I add that.

Comment: I am confused. What you are saying is that where the field ISNT required, then I should ad &nbsp;&nbsp; in place of it, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are center-aligning your form so it's child elements are going to be a bit goofy. Also, the `<label>` element generally doesn't surround the entire input element. Use the "for" attribute to match the id of your input.

You will need to use some CSS to tweak the layout a bit. Each browser is going to handle the form elements slightly different.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <p>
        <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
        <input name="fName" id="fName" type="text" required/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lName">Last Name:</label>
        <input name="lName" id="lName" type="text" />
    </p>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form label {
    display: block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8r51pay/)

Depending on how you want your form labels to look (above, inline etc) your css and container elements may need updated.

**EDIT**
[Here is an old Site Point Article](http://www.sitepoint.com/fancy-form-design-css-3/) that will help get the layout you are looking for.

Comment: But this changes the way he wants to display his form - labels inline with inputs.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a `<label>` surrounding an `<input>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label